# Basic proof of neural perceptron's behaviour

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

Recently I came up with this really interesting reading [Neural Networks and Deep Learning Book by Michael Nielsen](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html),

and as I'm thinking to build a neural network for my Bachelor's Project, I was trying to really understand the very basics of neural networks.
After a bit of introduction of what perceptron and sigmoids are, there's an exercise session.

The first exercise asks to show that multiplying weights and the bias of a perceptron network doesn't affect the final behaviour of the network.

e.g:

**Initial Situation**

output = 0 if  + b <= 0 , 1 otherwise

**After scaling weights and the bias by a constant factor k > 0**

output = 0 if  + kb <=0, 1 otherwise

How can I prove such thing?

Thanks.